# TortoiseSVN "Encountered an improper argument"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, windows-server-2008

I am trying to checkout an SVN repository with TortoiseSVN on windows server 2008.  I get the error message "Encountered an improper argument" during checkout and that is all.  Any idea what could be the problem here?

[image]

Comment: Is this when you Right Click, then "Checkout"? Or during the checkout process? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, right click then "SVN Checkout". What do you mean by checkout process? Its not the same as right click SVN checkout?  Here is a picture: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/842/svnz.jpg/

Comment: @Ian Is this Server 2008 64 bit and do you have TortoiseSVN 64 bit running on the machine? I seem to recall this happening with a 32 bit version of TortoiseSVN in a 64 bit OS environment.

Comment: Yes, this is 64 bit vista and 64 bit tortoiseSVN.  One thing I managed to do is checkout via command line, that works fine.
EDIT: I noticed that after I do a checkout via command line, all other GUI functions work properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is solved in the new 1.7.3 version. Tested on win7 x64.

Comment: I just did an install of version 1.7.11, Build 23600 64 bit on a new Win7 installation, and I'm getting the same bug/error message on every command.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem on Windows 7 64 bit, with version 1.7.2 of Tortoise SVN.  I uninstalled it and installed 1.7.1, and that worked around the problem.  (There is an Older Versions link at the bottom of the downloads page)

Comment: If on 1.7.1 you permanently accept the security certificate then you can update to 1.7.2

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be an bug related to server side certificates.

On a clean install of windows 7 64bit I got the same crash when browsing to an https site.

When running 1.7.1 (install from here)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/1.7.1/Application/

it brought up a warning about my invalid certificate which I could accept permanently, and it now works. 1.7.2 crashes and does not bring up the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, from http://svn.haxx.se/tsvnusers/archive-2010-03/0191.shtml

> Configure your virus scanner to leave the tortoiseproc.exe process
>   alone and make sure it doesn't 'sanitize' the network traffic.

Comment: Thanks but I saw that post and I don't have any virus scanner on this server.

Answer (score 0):

user1092552 just said it.
The problem seems to be with the certificate acceptance dialog.
On 1.7.2 it doesn't show and on its place we get the "Encountered an improper argument" error message.

What I did was:

1. uninstall 1.7.2
2. install 1.7.1
3. connect to my repository and accept the certificate permanently
4. update to 1.7.2

This way the certificate is already accepted and the dialog will no longer be requested.
Everything works as expexted.

Cheers!
Alex